# Reference request: matrix problems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, contest-math

I am going to participate in some low-tier undergraduate math olympiad and I want to practice solving linear algebra problems. Almost all olympiad linear algebra problems are somehow related to matrices. For example you are given large $n$ by $n$ matrix $A $ and you are asked to calculate determinant of it or find $tr(A^n)$ etc.

Could you please suggest me some book that has such kind of problems with solutions? I found some nice problems of this kind in Putnam and Beyond, but i believe its level is a little bit high for what I need.